# Pick Phone Number from contacts

Tags: android, contacts

I have doubt in that section. How to replace space between the string, when to get phone number from Contact list?
         And it's working fine, But some android devices(e.g. Samsung Tab) have 
    spaces added in their contacts. I get number from contact.So I get string 99 
    99 99999 instead of 99999999.

And also, How to eliminate country code from that number. 
  Ex: +91 999999999 instead of 9999999999 or +020 9696854549 instead of 9696854549

I know, remove that space by using .replace().
 Is there any other process to remove space between the string.

I attached my code:::

```
   public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
              startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, 
RESULT_PICK_CONTACT);
        }

private void contactPicked(Intent data) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String phoneNo = null ;
        // getData() method will have the Content Uri of the selected contact
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        //Query the content uri
        cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        // column index of the phone number
        int  phoneIndex =cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);

        phoneNo = cursor.getString(phoneIndex);

        mobile_et.setText(phoneNo);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could use https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber

Comment: https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace every white space in the phone number

```
phoneNo=phoneNo.replaceAll("\\s+","");
```

Answer (score 3):

The `String` class has a method:

```
.replace(char oldChar, char newChar)
```

It returns a new `String` resulting from replacing all occurrences of `oldChar` in this string with `newChar`. So you are just replacing all spaces with an empty `String` (i.e. `""`):

```
phoneNo = cursor.getString(phoneIndex);
String phoneNumber= str.replaceAll(" ", "");  // your string without any spaces
```