# how to remove country code and special character from given phone number?

Tags: android

How can I remove country code and special characters from my given phone number : +1-541-xxx-xxxx  I want as a result : 541xxxxxxx

```
  String edt = edittext.toString();
  String num = edt.substring(Math.max(edt.length() - 10, 0));
  result = num.replaceAll("-","")

if(s.length()>10) {

                String edt = s.toString();
                System.out.println("@@"+edt);

                System.out.println("== PHONE ==:"+edt.substring(Math.max(edt.length() - 10, 0)));
                String kk = edt.substring(Math.max(edt.length() - 10, 0));
                result = kk.replaceAll("-","");

                //edtSearch.setText(kk);
                System.out.println("== PHONE ==:"+kk);

            }
```

Comment: split on - , then join all elements starting from 1st element

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve here? You can set length limit and inputType to number in your xml, which will avoid input of special characters and will limit the maximum number of characters

Comment: i dont want to change on xml side i just want a actual 10 digits number from formatted phone number in a string. that string i need to send to my server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pick Phone Number from contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45435121/pick-phone-number-from-contacts)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to remove country code when i paste a phone number which is copied from another resource (need to remove special chars also )?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45475440/how-to-remove-country-code-when-i-paste-a-phone-number-which-is-copied-from-anot)

Comment: how this differs from your other question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 String number = "+1-541-8569-7896";
    String[] split = number.split("-",2);

    String num1 = split[1];
    num1=num1.replaceAll("[\\D]", "");
    Log.d("=============>>>",num1);
```

Comment: it removes all specail characters but country code wasnt removed with this code. here is this results is ::  154185697896